# Wordpress get most recent post from another db

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, content-management-system

I am trying to put the most recent post from another Wordpress DB in my footer.php file, but obviously am not understanding the concept. I'm new to WP and "the loop", so any help would be appreciated!

```
<!-- .entry-content -->
<?php
$originaldb = new wpdb('db_name', 'db_password', 'db_user', 'localhost'); //This has been replaced obviously.
$newestPost = $originaldb->query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0,1;");
$newestPost = mysql_fetch_array($newestPost);
        if ($newestPost) {
        foreach ($newestPost as $newPost) {
        ?>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <?php echo '<span class="entry-day">'.get_the_date('j').'</span><br><span class="entry-month">'.get_the_date('M').'</span>'; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="title-box">
                    <h2 class="blog-title"><a href="<?php //the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php echo '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ).'">'.get_the_author().'</a>'; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } //end foreach ?>
    <?php } //endif ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will gives the last post record.

```
<?php
$mydb = new wpdb('root','pass','dbname','localhost');
$lastpost = $mydb->get_results("SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,1");

echo $lastpost[0]->post_title;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do ... first, you shouldn't need a foreach loop since you're only planning to use one result row.  Second, why not directly access the values of $newestPost as an associative array?  See where I've added "$newestPost['theTitle']" to replace "the_title()", and I've done similarly for the the author and content as well.

```
if ($newestPost)  {
       ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php echo '<span class="entry-day">'.get_the_date('j').'</span><br><span class="entry-month">'.get_the_date('M').'</span>'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="title-box">
                <h2 class="blog-title"><a href="<?php //the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $newestPost['theTitle']; ?></a></h2>
                <?php echo '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ).'">'.$newestPost['theAuthor']).'</a>'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </header>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php echo $newestPost['theContent']; ?>
        </div>

    <?php
    } //endif ?>
```

You would need to replace 'theTitle' etc with whatever is in your db schema.  Hope that helps, I'm not big into WP so I might be missing something important but this seems universally applicable.

EDIT:  It looks like using mysql_fetch_array is [no longer recommended](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).